# Classifying local behavior of fixed points using eigenvalues from linear stability analysis of 3D system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-optimization

I've learned about classification of fixed points of 2D systems using linear stability analysis and I am wondering how if at all I can apply the same process to analyzing local behavior of fixed points in 3D systems.

I am specifically wondering about these cases:

- 1 positive, 2 distinct negative real eigenvalues
- 1 positive, 2 repeated negative real eigenvalues
- 1 positive, 2 complex eigenvalues with negative real part
- 1 negative, 2 complex eigenvalues with negative real part

In the first two cases I am guessing that it works something like 2D: the stable manifold is a 2D manifold and the unstable manifold is a curve. I am wondering what the difference would be between 2 distinct versus 2 repeated would be.

In the last two cases I am having trouble visualing what this would even look like.

Any help or resources are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the last two cases I am having trouble visualing what this would even look like.

Have a look at Fig. 2.4 (b) of [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=B6Z2TQSRJuMC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false).

In general, I do not know many sources that specifically distinguish between various cases as on the plane (note, e.g., that stable node is topologically equivalent to a stable focus, and so forth). However, in a very [old book by Nemytskii and Stepanov](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486659542) you can find a very detailed classification of various types of equilibria in ${\bf R}^n$.

Comment: Is there a reason why people don't focus on classification in higher dimensions (other than the fact that there are way more cases to classify)?

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos Because this classification does not add much to our understanding of the behavior of the orbits.

Answer (score 1):

In last two cases, the positive (negative) eigenvalue will correspond to a 1-D unstable(stable) manifold, normal to a plane in which you will see the stable focus.