# Is there a relationship between conservative vector field in calculus and Eigenvalue and Eigenvector in Linear Algebra?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I am a math student and now studying Calculus 4, I came across the subject of conservative vector field today.

The definition is that

A vector field F is called a conservative vector field if it is the gradient of some scalar function, that is, if there exists a function f such that $\mathbf{F}= ∇ f$ . In this situation f is called a potential function for F.

This just made me think of the association from what I learned from Linear Algebra. So, please give me some direction to start digging deeper to understand this concept. If there exists a connection.

Comment: What is it exactly about the definition of a conservative vector field that reminds you of eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you have in mind, exactly. The gradient map $\nabla$ is linear over $\Bbb R$, but its domain (say, the space of differentiable functions on $\Bbb R^n$) and codomain (say, the space of vector fields on $\Bbb R^n$) are different, so there is no notion of eigenvector available.

Answer (score 1):

One area of tangential relation that comes to mind, relating gradients, vector fields, potentials, and linear algebra, is non-linear dynamics. (Perhaps you're already familiar with it).

For instance, consider the following system:
$$
\frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial t} = f(\vec{x},t)
$$
where $\vec{x}(t)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and 
$f(\vec{x},t)=(f_1(\vec{x},t),\ldots,f_n(\vec{x},t))$. 
The Jacobian is then:
$$
J_p(t) = \begin{bmatrix}\nabla f_1\\\vdots\\\nabla f_n\end{bmatrix}_{\vec{x}=p}
$$
where the gradients are treated as row vectors.
The Jacobian matrix allows one to compute the [stability of fixed points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_stability). (Also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory)). The eigenvalues and eigenvectors essentially determine the behaviour of the system around those points (e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369976/classifying-local-behavior-of-fixed-points-using-eigenvalues-from-linear-stabili?rq=1)).

Here, again, we find the notion of conservative systems.
For instance, if $V$ is a potential function, the system:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}x(t)=−\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}
$$
is a conservative one. (Notice the analogy to your example: $f(\vec{x},t)=-\nabla V$.) See Strogatz's book on non-linear dynamics and chaos.
One example from there is
$$
m\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}x(t) = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}
$$
for which one can show that the total energy
$$
E=\frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)^2 + V(x)
$$
is always conserved over time. (Notice term 1 is kinetic energy and term 2 is potential energy.)
As before, in such systems, the stability behaviour of the system is determined by the spectrum of the Jacobian!